# ...because any signs "would/will" be the potential indicators - second conditional structure should I use would or will?

Tags: conditionals

**Example one**

"If you had close contact with Covid patients, you would have to pay more attention to your body because any signs **would/will** be the potential indicators."

This is a second conditional structure. I wonder which one I should use will or would?

Comment: The whole sentence is unreal, so the whole sentence uses unreal grammar, including the "because" clause

Comment: I think you probably mean symptoms, not signs. The whole sentence needs re-writing as @gotube remarked but proof reading is off topic here.

Comment: @mdewey I didn't recommend rewriting. I talked about what kind of grammar it had and concluded that only "would" is a correct choice there.

Answer (score 1):

**Would** is probably most appropriate since the entire sentence is hypothetical.

Comment: Well since the whole ting is ungrammatical how can we tell which it should be?